# Windows service can't start

Tags: vb.net, events, service

Entire code in service is

```
 Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
        ' in motion so your service can do its work.
        While 1 = 1
            Try
                Dim mLoop As New Init
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End While
    End Sub
```

And on Init constructor i have code

```
 Public Sub New()
        Dim rIni As New cIniFile

        Dim strPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
        strPath = New Uri(strPath).LocalPath
        rIni.Filename = strPath & "\Configuration.ini"
        rIni.LoadFromFile()

        ' TIME FOR Advertising 
        If (Format(Date.Now, "dddd") = "Monday" And rIni.ReadString("SMS_Advertise", "ADV_Mo", 0) = 1 And Format(CDate(rIni.ReadString("SMS_Advertise", "TimeSend")), "hh:mm") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")) Or
           (Format(Date.Now, "dddd") = "Tuesday" And rIni.ReadString("SMS_Advertise", "ADV_Tu", 0) = 1 And Format(CDate(rIni.ReadString("SMS_Advertise", "TimeSend")), "hh:mm") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")) Or
           (Format(Date.Now, "dddd") = "Wednesday" And rIni.ReadString("SMS_Advertise", "ADV_We", 0) = 1 And Format(CDate(rIni.ReadString("SMS_Advertise", "TimeSend")), "hh:mm") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")) Or
           (Format(Date.Now, "dddd") = "Thursday" And rIni.ReadString("SMS_Advertise", "ADV_Th", 0) = 1 And Format(CDate(rIni.ReadString("SMS_Advertise", "TimeSend")), "hh:mm") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")) Or
           (Format(Date.Now, "dddd") = "Friday" And rIni.ReadString("SMS_Advertise", "ADV_Fr", 0) = 1 And Format(CDate(rIni.ReadString("SMS_Advertise", "TimeSend")), "hh:mm") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")) Or
           (Format(Date.Now, "dddd") = "Saturday" And rIni.ReadString("SMS_Advertise", "ADV_Sa", 0) = 1 And Format(CDate(rIni.ReadString("SMS_Advertise", "TimeSend")), "hh:mm") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")) Or
           (Format(Date.Now, "dddd") = "Sunday" And rIni.ReadString("SMS_Advertise", "ADV_Su", 0) = 1 And Format(CDate(rIni.ReadString("SMS_Advertise", "TimeSend")), "hh:mm") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")) Then
            ProcessStart(strPath & "\tSMSAdvertise.exe")
        End If

        ' TIME FOR Notifications 
        If (Format(Date.Now, "dddd") = "Monday" And rIni.ReadString("SMS_Notification", "ADV_Mo", 0) = 1 And Format(CDate(rIni.ReadString("SMS_Notification", "TimeSend")), "hh:mm") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")) Or
         (Format(Date.Now, "dddd") = "Tuesday" And rIni.ReadString("SMS_Notification", "ADV_Tu", 0) = 1 And Format(CDate(rIni.ReadString("SMS_Notification", "TimeSend")), "hh:mm") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")) Or
         (Format(Date.Now, "dddd") = "Wednesday" And rIni.ReadString("SMS_Notification", "ADV_We", 0) = 1 And Format(CDate(rIni.ReadString("SMS_Notification", "TimeSend")), "hh:mm") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")) Or
         (Format(Date.Now, "dddd") = "Thursday" And rIni.ReadString("SMS_Notification", "ADV_Th", 0) = 1 And Format(CDate(rIni.ReadString("SMS_Notification", "TimeSend")), "hh:mm") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")) Or
         (Format(Date.Now, "dddd") = "Friday" And rIni.ReadString("SMS_Notification", "ADV_Fr", 0) = 1 And Format(CDate(rIni.ReadString("SMS_Notification", "TimeSend")), "hh:mm") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")) Or
         (Format(Date.Now, "dddd") = "Saturday" And rIni.ReadString("SMS_Notification", "ADV_Sa", 0) = 1 And Format(CDate(rIni.ReadString("SMS_Notification", "TimeSend")), "hh:mm") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")) Or
         (Format(Date.Now, "dddd") = "Sunday" And rIni.ReadString("SMS_Notification", "ADV_Su", 0) = 1 And Format(CDate(rIni.ReadString("SMS_Notification", "TimeSend")), "hh:mm") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")) Then
            ProcessStart(strPath & "\tSMSDate.exe")
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessStart(path As String)
        Dim proc As New Process
        proc = Process.Start(path)
        proc.WaitForExit()
    End Sub
```

But yet, after installing that service i have problem with starting it. I cant figure out why it popup

> service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely
>   fashion

In event logger i don't have anything instead of shown on picture under

[image: Event logger]

Also i checked the Main sub and its not in debug mode

```
 Shared Sub Main()

        '#If DEBUG Then
        '        Dim servicio As New Service1
        '        servicio.OnStart(Nothing)
        '        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
        '#Else
        Dim ServicesToRun() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase
        ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New Service1}
        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
        '#End If

    End Sub
```

Anyone have idea what am i missing.

Comment: Your issue is in your OnStart. Do not do a loop that will always be true, use onStart to create a thread that does the work you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a while true in your OnStart, your service will never successfully start. Instead create a thread to do what you need. Like so:

```
 Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
    ' in motion so your service can do its work.
    dim T as new Thread(AddressOf MainWorker)
    T.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub MainWorker()
        While 1 = 1
        Try
            Dim mLoop As New Init
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't figure out  
Error BC30518 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Overloads Sub New(start As ThreadStart)': Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.

Comment: Got it and fixed it

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out :)

Comment: i still didn't sorted out. It works as a charm in debug mode. But when i run it it doesn't do anything :(

Comment: could use your help here

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't do anything?

Comment: Make sure you're running as user and not system. `Process.Start()` as SYSTEM will not do anything

Comment: Is there any way you provide me support via TW or Google remote. I promise i just want to show you 2 minutes not longer ?

Comment: This is second thread with current problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138540/service-work-in-debug-mode-only