# Service work in debug mode only

Tags: vb.net, service

Can't figure why my windows service work only in debug mode.

Only three functions used.

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
Shared Sub Main()

    'Dim servicio As New Service1
    'servicio.OnStart(Nothing)
    'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)

    WriteLog("Starting it")
    Dim ServicesToRun() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase
    ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New Service1}
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)

End Sub

Public Sub MainWorker()
    While 1 = 1
        Try
            Dim mLoop As New Init
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End While
End Sub
```

While its on debug mode it goes as a charm on method OnStart.

```
  Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
        ' in motion so your service can do its work.

        Try
            Dim T As New Thread(AddressOf MainWorker)
            T.Start()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
```

But when its used without debug ( Installed and run ) it doesn't popup any error message. Status is running. But nothing happens. Not even the log message "Starting it" ...

Edit: Init class on pastebin [PASTEBIN.INIT](https://pastebin.com/yeD5LxLW)

Comment: It probably doesn't pop up an error message because you are swallowing your exceptions.  Try putting some kind of logging inside of your catch blocks.

Comment: @tgolisch I put logger back in this. It seems like service doesnt run this INIT at all or even doesnt go on OnStart method :S

Comment: Check your Windows Event logs. Are they capturing any errors when your service starts?

Comment: @tgolisch doesnt capturing any errors

Comment: is your service actually running? check services.msc to see if your service is started correctly.

Comment: @Jaxi i checked it Its up and running. I have worked before with services. When i put to create event log on start. also when i put to write in .txt file nothing happens. Seems like it does not go to OnStart method at all

Comment: take a look at this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/88b5f0d6-e692-4441-a20f-37f6447359d4/method-not-called-from-onstart-of-windows-service?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: @jaxi Its already set up to run under admin account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is i should think outside the box for some reason when i put path to log file like this

```
Public Sub WriteLog2(sLine As String)
        Dim strFile As String = "Service_Log.txt"
        Dim fileExists As Boolean = File.Exists(strFile)
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(strFile, FileMode.Append))
            sw.WriteLine(sLine)
        End Using

        Console.WriteLine(sLine)
    End Sub
```

It does not work because i need to enter the full path to Service_Log.txt file.

Comment: You are not using the built in logging?

Comment: It's step 5 of the microsoft service guide. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer